# Issue with flow of a program

Tags: java

I am new to Java and just learning the basics.

I have gone through if checks/statements(if-if-if; if-else if-else, if-else), while and for loops as well. I have an assignment which I can not for the life of me figure out. I am having some issues with the flow of the program itself and I just get it to work half way through in Eclipse.

The idea of the program is for it to accept three integers from the keyboard(keyboard input using Scanner) and print out all numbers, between 0 and the first integer from the input, which can be divided by the second and third input integers, respectively. The first input integer has to be between 200 and 100. I will provide what code I have written. I can get the program to accept input but then I get the  message in the console.

I set up the three integers, I set up a condition for the first integer using a while loop and then I use a for loop to print all the numbers between 0 and the first input integer. Then within the for loop I do in if check and print out all the numbers. It accepts the input three times but then I just goes to terminated status.

```java
package Javawork;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    private static Scanner keyboard;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        firstProgramme();
    }

    public static void firstProgramme() {
        keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter number: ");
        int firstNum = keyboard.nextInt();
        int secondNum = keyboard.nextInt();
        int thirdNum = keyboard.nextInt();

        while (firstNum > 100 && firstNum < 200) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= firstNum; i++) {
                if (i % secondNum == 0 && i % thirdNum == 0) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using a while loop on a value that never changes within the loop, firstNum -- why? What purpose does this serve?

Comment: So first of all: get rid of the while loop as it's only hurting you.

Comment: Replace `while` with `if` otherwise you'll get an infinite loop (since if it's true once, it will continue to be true forever)

Comment: A key technique that you're not yet doing and must learn to progress is to walk through your code mentally or on paper, and ask yourself what your code is doing at each step. This is very similar to [rubber duck debugging](https://rubberduckdebugging.com/). The more you practice doing this, the better you'll get at it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how do you know they aren't?

Comment: @Michael: perhaps they are, but if so, they need to keep doing it, exercise the muscle and get better at it then. And I'm not meaning it as criticism but more as guidance.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I actually always start with kind of a flow chart or whatever. Maybe the explanation of the assignment was too confusing when I read it. Anyway, thanks for the very constructive ideas, I had no idea the duck technique existed even hahaha. Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you need to check whether the first number is between 100 and 200. For that you should use

```
    if(firstNum > 100 && firstNum < 200) {
```

instead of

```
    while(firstNum > 100 && firstNum < 200) {
```

As if will check the condition and while will iterate based on condition.